# How to create a new Highlighter (SynEdit)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, synedit

I'm relatively new on Delphi, but after installed SynEdit componnent, I can't create my own highlighter yet. I already generated the .pas with mine highlighting configs. I tried from all the ways I know. But I can't use the generated file to highlight. Can anyone help me?

I thank  in advance...

Comment: Did you read this wiki article? http://wiki.freepascal.org/SynEdit_Highlighter

Comment: Now I did, but it did not solved my doubt. Just teach many things to do after installed a Highlighter.

Comment: Well... I solved my problem. Should I answer my own question for future same doubts? (I'm new on StackOverFlow too)

Comment: ye u should. for other guys who got the same problem as you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, people. I already solved my problem. Actually it was so simple. To use the generated .PAS, just include it in the project and assign in the **USES** statemments. After that, you need to assign the custom highlighter to a SynComponent in RunTime.
Like this:

```
var
   HL : TSynSampleSyn;
begin
   HL := TSynSampleSyn.Create(Self);
   SynEdit1.Highlighter := HL;
end;
```

After execute this block, the SynEdit will be ready for use.